# W3C Standards: Is it bad form to create a new tag for custom app parsing purposes?

Tags: html, w3c

Like... lets say I want to create a `<selection>` tag in order to store a users selection within the body of some text.

does that create any problems for browsers (like as far as rendering, etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using the HTML5 `<mark>` element.

See: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/text-level-semantics.html#the-mark-element

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can and no, it doesn't. You're always welcome to create your own elements/tags in HTML, the W3C validator will just throw a lot of flags because you're not following the official HTML standards. A browser will treat unknown elements as 'just being there' until you use CSS to style them. Since you made them up, they won't be in the default stylesheet so no styles will be applied to them, making it seem like it wasn't even there (by default).

So, if you don't care about what the W3C validator says, do whatever you like. Adding extra tags will not break any browsers, and they can still parse CSS for them fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're better of using "data-" attributes on existing tags. I don't think custom tags will break anything, although the semantic meaning of them steps outside of existing expectations.

Comment: See: http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

"Custom data attributes are intended to store custom data private to the page or application, for which there are no more appropriate attributes or elements."